# Copiar e colar em planilhas diferentes no Google Sheets

Tags: google, google-charts, google-drive-api

Estou tentando copiar um valor de uma tabela e enviar para outra usando o script do Google Sheets, mas recebo o seguinte erro `Target range and source range must be on the same spreadsheet`

```
function myFunction() {
var ss1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet ();
var ss2 = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1wIVQA-QhgSvTpmrIl4R6Gwhh1pMKcVKEcdFPa8_KTXw");
var source = ss2.getRange ("Moz!D2:J2");
var destiny = ss1.getRange("Sheet1!A2:B2");
source.copyTo (destiny, {contentsOnly: true});
source.clear ();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Utilize a função `IMPORTRANGE(spreadsheet_key, range_string)` do próprio Google Sheets.

Link para te ajudar:
http://www.mousewhisperer.co.uk/drivebunny/using-importrange-in-google-sheets/

```
function myFunction() {

  var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1HjOhDmBrzLZ1UyB9P-HuF0gJbfngW03zdOWWFNjS708");

  sheets.getSheetByName("Sheet1").getRange("A1").setFormula("=IMPORTRANGE(\"https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1uJkUxmkDHKaTghy-H4_YQ3ILKRurEkSEbR5UAy8SrIQ/edit#gid=0\",\"A1:C3\")");  
}
```